# Windows 7 flash monitor black?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, dvi, displayport

I have a laptop connected to a monitor that uses Displayport. My monitor flashes black for a split second randomly while connected to Displayport but does not while connected via DVI out.

I've swapped out the Displayport cable and the docking station. The monitor still flashed black.

However, I think I may have discovered the problem. Under the display->advanced properties. My Windows detects my laptop display as a secondary device. Ironically when I have set the screen to Do not extend then it flashes black.

It looks like that setting my monitor to extend to an unconnected DVI cable then it fixes the problem or possibly extend to LCD.

Does anyone know if this is indeed the problem and how I can set it not to extend but to work?

I know it doesn't make any sense unless it has something to do with a powersaving option or something.

Comment: Sounds to me like a driver issue more than a physical problem. Have you checked that you have the latest drivers?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there any appliances or radios nearby?  I've seen some DisplayPort cables that are very sensitive to EMF interference.

Comment: @Shinrai Not that I'm aware of. See my updated description. seems when I have the DVI plugged into the docking station it doesn't do it even when using displayport

Comment: Yeah, that's really weird. I dunno.  What model laptop is this anyway?