# Monitor gives black screen automatically

Tags: windows-7, display

My monitor gives a black screen automatically. When I turn on the computer, it is working normally, but when I am at the login screen, after a few seconds it will just flash a bit and turn off.

Then I do the following:
 - Press the Windows button + P
 - Press the right arrow
 - Press Enter

The problem is now solved, but after like 10 seconds it will flash again and I am getting the exact same problem. I can continue using this quick-fix, but it is very annoying.

Also, the strange thing is, that it sometimes actually works normally. I can work for hours just fine. But when I shutdown my PC and start it again, the problem might be back again.

I have a Geforce 7600GS video card and downloaded and installed the latest drives from the official Nvidia website.

Any suggestions on what the problem is and how to solve?

**UPDATE**
I experience the same problem when I turn on the monitor on a different computer.

**UPDATE 2**
I could work with the monitor for a whole afternoon without any problems. But I wanted to change the brightess, so I opened the menu of the monitor and changed the brightness. Then the monitor turned off suddenly.

Now every time I apply one of the quick-fixes (e.g. turning the monitor on and off) it starts working again, but just for 1 or 2 seconds. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Does the monitor turn off during use, or only when it's idle?  If only when it's idle does it solely turn off when you're on the login screen or everywhere?

Comment: @KronoS: Everywhere. I can also use just do thing on my computer, but I just don't see what I am doing. So I am using this quick-fix and I can log in. Then whatever I do, either nothing or anything, it just quickly flashes and turns off.

Comment: From what I can gather it sounds like a hardware issue... do you have the same problem with another monitor?

Comment: @KronoS: I don't have another monitor here at the moment. But I found another quick-fix. That is to turn the monitor off and on. Then it will work again.

Comment: @Kronos: But the problem is still not solved.

Comment: The problem is not solved by switching out monitors?

Comment: @KronoS: Nope. It does the same as the Windows button + P fix.

Answer (score 1):

It most likely is not any setting, but you can try restoring the monitor to default settings and see if that helps, its worth a shot as it is very simple to do.
Try replacing the monitor cable, there could be an issue with cable or one of the connectors that is causing intermittent issues. If that doesn't change anything, try swapping out the power cable (it is a long-shot, but I've seen defective power cables cause all sorts of odd issues in equipment).
If none of this works, then it would appear to be a hardware issue with the monitor, possibly some sort of short. I would suggest contacting the manufacturer to see if they have any diagnostic tests that you can run on their monitors or to see if it is a known issue with the equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Your monitor will have a power management function. Try turning it off.

Look for references to DVI DMPM in the manual. If that solves the problem then you could just switch off the monitor when you are finished with the computer.

I only know this because some people at work changed the timeout on this function to different values on different monitors and i had them randomly turn off on me. Took a couple of days before i realized they were screwing with me. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think this is the case for my monitor. The monitor doesn't turn off, it just gives a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

In the thread [Windows 7 flash monitor black](https://superuser.com/questions/212800/windows-7-flash-monitor-black) the poster remarks :

> Under the display->advanced
>   properties. My Windows detects my
>   laptop display as a secondary device.
>   Ironically when I have set the screen
>   to Do not extend then it flashes
>   black.
>
> It looks like that setting my monitor
>   to EXTEND to an unconnected DVI cable
>   then it fixes the problem or possibly
>   EXTEND to LCD.

Does this relate to your problem ? You can see the monitor setup with right-click on the desktop, then select "Screen resolution".

Comment: Thanks, but no, I don't think so. I am having the same problem if I attach the monitor on my laptop. It outputs correctly, but after 2 seconds it just goes black. How can this be?

Comment: I would say that the monitor is misbehaving, maybe a hardware problem. Have you tried another monitor? Is it new enough to be under warranty?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but your monitor really is broken so you either need to get it fixed or get a replacement.

There is nothing more that you can do yourself, unless you have knowledge about electricity/electronics...

---

It's most likely to be a loose contact, bad capacitors or a problem with it's power circuit...

In which case it causes your monitor to turn off when there is an increase of brightness; for example, the loading screen is mostly black but at the login screen it requires a lot more color and thus more power.

That power now goes somewhere else or short circuits which causes the safety circuit to turn the monitor off.